# Composing a command bus using RX

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm getting familiar with RX and as my experimental project I'm trying to create a simple command bus conceptually similar to this:

```
class Bus
{
    Subject<Command> commands;
    IObservable<Invocation> invocations;

    public Bus()
    {
        this.commands = new Subject<Command>();
        this.invocations = commands.Select(x => new Invocation { Command = x }).Publish();
    }

    public IObserver<Command> Commands
    {
        get { return this.commands; }
    }

    public IObservable<Invocation> Invocations
    {
        get { return this.invocations; }
    }
}

class Invocation
{
    public Command Command { get; set; }
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that modules can install command handlers at startup using the `Invocations` property and can apply any filtering they wish to their subscription. Clients on the other hand can trigger command execution by calling `Commands.OnNext(command)`.

However, I would like the Bus to provide a guarantee that each command submitted will be handled by exactly one handler. That is, `OnNext` processing should ideally terminate as soon as the first handler sets Invocation.Handled to true AND should throw an exception if, at the conclusion of `OnNext()`, `Invocation.Handled` is still false.

I played around creating my own ISubject, IObservable and IObserver implementations but this feels "dirty and cheap" ;)

I'm endeavouring to get my head around the compositional power that RX provides. In a  compositional way, how can I provide the "exactly once" guarantee?

Thanks for any insights you can provide.

Comment: Wouldn't the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) be more suitable here?

Comment: Thanks @dtb. Chain of responsibility may well be useful in managing processing once a handler has been selected. There are more simpler and effective approaches to building a command bus than this one. However, my question is more about the concepts of RX and composability.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe. No I have not come across it. Just had a quick look and it appears to be another compositional approach that might be more appropriate to this problem. Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've generally got the right idea here, actually. You just need to do the actual dispatch. For this, SelectMany will help:

```
class Bus
{
    Subject<Command> commands;
    Subject<Invocation> invocations;

    // TODO: Instantiate me
    List<Func<Command, bool>> handlerList; 

    public Bus()
    {
        this.commands = new Subject<Command>();
        this.invocations = new Subject<Invocation>();

        commands.SelectMany(x => {
            // This FirstOrDefault() is just good ol' LINQ
            var passedHandler = 
                handlerList.FirstOrDefault(handler => handler(x) == true);

            return passedHandler != null ?
                Observable.Return(new Invocation() { Command = x, Handled = true}) :
                Observable.Throw<Invocation>(new Exception("Unhandled!"));
        }).Multicast(invocations).Connect();
    }

    /* ... snip ... */
}
```

But, to be honest, this doesn't really demonstrate the power of Rx, because it's executing the handler list synchronously. Let's make this more compelling by making this completely non-blocking.

First, we'll change our Func prototype to be `Func<Command, IObservable<Invocation>>`. This means, a method that takes a command and produces a Future Invocation result (a-la `Task<T>`). Then, we can get identical behavior yet have our handlers be async via this selector (coding via TextArea ahead):

```
commands.SelectMany(x =>
    handlerList.ToObservable()
        .Select(h => Observable.Defer(() => h(x)))
        .Concat()
        .SkipWhile(x => x.Handled == false)
        .TakeLast(1))
    .Multicast(invocations).Connect();
```

This is a pretty graduate-level use of Rx, but the idea is, for each Command, we're going to initially create a Stream of handlers and run them in order (that's what Defer + Concat does), until we find one whose Handled is true, then take the last one.

The outer SelectMany selects a stream of Commands into a Stream of Future Results (i.e. the type is `IO<IO<Invocation>>` then flattens it, so it becomes a stream of results.

No blocking ever, very concise, 100% testable, type-safe code that just expressed a pretty complicated idea that would've been really ugly to write imperatively. This is why Rx is cool.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This will take a little time to get my head properly around but is showing the compositional power I was hoping to see. Will study it closely.

I note that the point @Gideon made about ALL observers being notified has also shaped your solution. Essentially that IO<Invocation> subscriptions cannot be the mechanism for handlers to tegister themselves with the bus.

Comment: .TakeWhile(x => x.Handled == false)
.TakeLast(1) I didn't try this, but won't I get the final Observable with the last unhandled, instead of the first handled? I would do .SkipWhile(x => x.Handled == false).Take(1). Is this true, or am I thinking it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While maybe you *can* make an "exactly once" subject, you *shouldn't*.  The interface (and all the operators in the library) implies that all observers will be notified (ignoring the possibility of exceptions in OnNext calls).

What you could do is create an alternate set of interfaces that define your desired semantics:

```
interface IHandlableObservable<T>
{
    //gets first chance at the notification
    IDisposable SubscribeFirst(IHandlingObserver<T> observer);
    //gets last chance at the notification
    IDisposable SubscribeLast(IHandlingObserver<T> observer);
    //starts the notification (possibly subscribing to an underlying IObservable)
    IDisposable Connect();
}

interface IHandlingObserver<T>
{
    //return indicates if the observer "handled" the value
    bool OnNext(T value);
    void OnError(Exception ex);
    void OnCompleted();
}
```

You can then define methods that allow you convert regular observables to handlable observables so that you can keep most of the logic in the standard RX operators.

Comment: Thanks @Gideon. Yeah I was wondering whether this simply was not a problem well suited to solving with RX. But I wasn't sure if I simply hadn't yet made the mind shift necessary to find a compositional solution.